# How to show server side validation error in MVC view page while calling the action method using Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am new to MVC knockout, can anyone help me out.

I am calling a MVC4 webapi action method in ajax call using knockout js .
when I Click the login button it calls the WebApi Action method .let us consider the that UserID and password is Invalid when How can I show the Error message in the View .

```
var User = function () {
    this.Email = ko.observable();
    this.Password = ko.observable();
};


var LoginViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.IncorrectLogin = ko.observable(false);

    this.User = ko.observable(new User());
    this.Login = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api/Login/PostAddUser',
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "{'Email':'" + self.User.Email + "' , 'password':'" + self.User.Password + "'}",
            success: function (data,status,xhttps) {
                var result = data;
                if (data == true) {
                    window.location.href = '../User/Account';
                } else {

                }
            },
            error: function (data, status, xhttps) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    };

};
ko.applyBindings(new LoginViewModel());
```

So if that userid and password is not valid I want to show some message in the view .
How can I pass the error message from controller to View?

```
 public bool PostAddUser(User user)
        {
            User u = DataAccessLayer.ValidateUser(User.email, User.password);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Id) || u.Id == 0)
            {
                //retun the custome validation error like Invalid UserId
            }
            else
            {
                if (u.activeCodeConfirmed)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems like you have the following already set up:

1. `this.IncorrectLogin = ko.observable(false);`
2. `if (data == true) { window.location.href = '../User/Account'; } else { \\Do something }`

First off, it's a good idea to bind your model's `this` into a variable so you won't get mixed up all the `this` you'll be encountering in callbacks.

So, you can do something like the following:

```
var self = this;
self.IncorrectLogin = ko.observable(false);
//... other code
```

So in your AJAX callback, if the login is false, you can update this observable, like so:

```
if (data == true) { 
    window.location.href = '../User/Account'; 
} else { 
    self.IncorrectLogin(true); 
}
```

Now that you have a way to notify KO of this incorrect login, you can choose to display an error message or something in your HTML form. Sample:

```
<div data-bind="visible: IncorrectLogin">
    <span style="color: red">I will only show up if it's an incorrect login!</span>
</div>
```

And that's the basics of how you do view updates using KO.

Now, if you have an error message coming from your server, say `data.message`, then you just take the same concept and make a message observable. Kinda like so:

```
self.ErrorMessage = ko.observable('');

//AJAX callback
if (data.valid) { 
    window.location.href = '../User/Account'; 
} else { 
    self.ErrorMessage(data.message); 
}
```

And in your HTML,

```
<div data-bind="visible: ErrorMessage() != ''">
    <span style="color: red" data-bind="text: ErrorMessage"></span>
</div>
```

Note that KO observables are functions, but you don't need to use the `()` notation if the observable is not part of an expression. See `visible: ErrorMessage() != ''` vs. `text: ErrorMessage`.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hi  Jensen Ching ,
How can i get the server side Errors in the ajax success method?
Let us consider that userid is not exist I want to show the message like UserId doesnot Exist and in some case I want to show like Password is wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically, you just need to pass the error message in the JSON result you're passing from the server to the client. Like `data.message` for example.

Comment: Basically @jensen chang I have other conditions also I am checking according to that Condition i ma returning true/False(if user exist) but if user does not exist I want to return some customise error messages from Controller to View
hope u understand my problem :)

Comment: You'll have to figure it out on the server-side as I'm not familiar with .NET MVC, but the gist of it is: Right now, your "data" result from the server is just a boolean value. If you want to return a string, make this result an object that contains, say, properties called `valid` and `message`. Then on the server side, after failing validation, populate this object, e.g. `valid=false, message="Custom message", then pass this result back to the client. After which, the code I provided can help you display your custom error message.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question if your question is more towards the server-side, as right now, it seems to be focused on client-side problems, so you'll keep getting client-side responses.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery and send a message to

```
<span id="messageError" style="display:none; color:red"> </span>
```

which will be under input login and pass.

```
if (data == true) {
                    window.location.href = '../User/Account';
                } else {
                    $('span#messageError').text('user and password is not valid');
                    $('span#messageError').css('display','inline');
                }
```

later to input username or password, you can do onclick = "hideMessage()" which will hide

```
function hideMessage ()
{
$('span#messageError').css('display','none');
}
```